# How to root Lenovo A319?

Tags: rooting, lenovo

I have a Lenovo A319 and Kingo Root didn't work on it. I badly need to root my phone because it has collected lots of bloatware. Please help.

Comment: @Manubhargav just saying, but LMGTFY is considered rude. A better solution is to provide the key word, and at least 1 direct related-link (e.g. XDA forum)

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh, I posted that as a fun way of saying google it. But thanks for letting me know about it

Answer (score 0):

- Try "Root Genius for PC" to root your phone.
- Download it from here [Root Genius for PC](http://rootgenius.com/)
- Install it on your PC, Run the Software.
- Connect your Phone with PC using USB Debugging.
  When your Phone get connected-> You will see in the Software, there is root button, Click on that, wait for 15-20 minutes.
- After sometime, your phone get rooted, and you can see "Kinguser" app is been installed.